# No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, encryption

I have a problem with my laravel install. The error message (shown below) happens from time to time (maybe somewhere around every 100 clicks).

I did the `php artisan key:generate` command.

I also checked the `APP_KEY` value in my `.env` file: it's formatted like that `base64:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

In my config/app.php I have the following code: `'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC'`

I don't see where the problem comes from... Could it be because of a length difference between the two variables? But if it does, why is it happening just randomly like that?

```
RuntimeException in EncryptionServiceProvider.php line 45:
No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.
in EncryptionServiceProvider.php line 45
at EncryptionServiceProvider->getEncrypterForKeyAndCipher(null, 'AES-256-CBC') in EncryptionServiceProvider.php line 25
at EncryptionServiceProvider->Illuminate\Encryption\{closure}(object(Application), array()) in Container.php line 731
at Container->build(object(Closure), array()) in Container.php line 629
at Container->make('encrypter', array()) in Application.php line 697
at Application->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Encryption\Encrypter') in Container.php line 849
at Container->resolveClass(object(ReflectionParameter)) in Container.php line 804
at Container->getDependencies(array(object(ReflectionParameter)), array()) in Container.php line 775
at Container->build('Sparta\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies', array()) in Container.php line 629
at Container->make('Sparta\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies', array()) in Application.php line 697
at Application->make('Sparta\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies') in Pipeline.php line 126
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 726
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 699
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the **.env** file set `APP_KEY=` (without value) and save.
Then run the following commands:

```
php artisan key:generate
php artisan config:cache
```

It works for me.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this. I'll see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: So apparently, after 2 weeks, it seems to have fixed the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your key in the .env file.

Run `php artisan key:generate` to generate a new one.

Then check if the key in the .env file changed. if not change it manually.

Comment: It seems the length of the generated key does not comply with the length that is expected

Comment: Then try to change your `'cipher' => 'AES-256-CBC'` to `'cipher' => 'AES-516-CBC'`

Comment: I tried that and it makes the problem worse: I got this error message for every click

Answer (score 0):

I managed to trigger this message by clicking several times in a row on the same button at a very fast pace if that can help...